# VIDIOC_DQBUF too slow for requested FPS

Tags: c, v4l2

I use V4L2 to get frames from my web camera, but I found out that even with `timeperframe` equal to `1/30`, call to `ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buffer)` takes ~60ms which is too slow! 30 frames * 60ms = 1800ms, almost 2 seconds to shoot 30 frames, this is ~15fps!

Also, I found out that if I decrease resolution by half (640x480 -> 320x240), the duration of VIDIOC_DQBUF call also decreases by half.

Can I do something with this or this is the limits of my hardware? Maybe there's something I should set up before open the stream?

I use Logitech C270 Web camera and source code in C is [here](https://github.com/JustSlavic/timelapser/blob/master/mwe.c#L309), if you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

“camera.init_buffers(2);”  try a larger buffer size here.